# How to configure includegraphics?

Tags: graphics

I want to know how can I configure an image with \includegraphics

Comment: There's nothing to configure, normally. What are you thinking of?

Comment: Welcome! Like Bernard says, there's nothing to do. You just include it, unless you need something special, in which case, you look at the manual or whatever. What's the problem? What code do you have? How are you trying to configure what?

Comment: Hello Thiago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, be sure that you have  inserted a line with `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble (somewhere between `\documentclass` line and   `\begin{document}`) although in some document class as `beamer` the package is already loaded by default, so this is not always necessary (but usually it is).

As  many other LaTeX commands, `\includegraphics` can be "configured"  through  optional arguments between brackets, before the mandatory argument (the filename of a PDF, JPG or PNG  image, with or without the extension) between curly braces. That is:

```
\includegraphics[option,option, ...  ]{filename}
```

e.g.:

```
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
```

A minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=.10,angle=45]{example-image.png}
\end{document}
```

The available options such as `width` or `keepaspectratio` are described in the subsections 4.4 of [user-manual for the packages color, graphics, and graphicx packages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).  You can see also the thousands of MWE in this site using the `\includegraphics` options.